# Probability defective items

Tags: probability

Two shipments of parts are received. The first shipment contain 1000 parts with 10% defective and the second contain 2000 parts with 5% defectives. Two parts are selected from a shipment selected at random and they are found to be good. Find the probability that the tested parts were from 1st shipment?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the event the parts were selected from the first shipment, and let $G$ be the event they are both good.

We want the probability they are from the first shipment, **given** they are both good. So we want $\Pr(A|G)$.

By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(A|G)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap G)}{\Pr(G)}.\tag{1}$$

We find the two probabilities on the right-hand side of (1).

The event $G$ can happen in two disjoint ways: (i) we select from the first shipment, and both items are good or (ii) we select from the second shipment, and both items are good.

We find the probability of (i). The probability we choose from the first shipment is $\frac{1}{2}$. **Given** that we selected from the first shipment, the probability they were both good is $\frac{900}{1000}\cdot \frac{899}{999}$.

Thus the probability of (i) is $\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{900}{1000}\cdot\dfrac{899}{999}$.

Similarly, find the probability of (ii). Add to get $\Pr(G)$.

Note that the numerator in Formula (1) is just what we called the probability of (i).

**Remark:** We interpreted "$10\%$ bad" literally, as in exactly $10$ percent, that is, exactly $100$ bad items in the group of $1000$. However, another reasonable interpretation is that the first shipment comes from a supplier who has a $10\%$ bad rate. Then we would replace $\frac{900}{1000}\cdot \frac{899}{999}$ by $\left(\frac{90}{100}\right)^2$. Numerically, it makes no practical difference.

Comment: how can the probability of choosing from 1st shipment is half?. When the shipment contain 1000 parts and second shipment contains 2000 parts. The probability of choosing two parts should be 1000C2/3000C2

Comment: It is a matter of interpretation. The problem says that two parts are selected from a **shipment** chosen at random. Of course, "at random" could have many meanings, for example we could select the first shipment with probability $1/10$, the second with probability $9/10$. But in problems, when we have two choices $P$ and $Q$, and we are told that we choose between them at random, the conventional meaning is each with probability $1/2$. Really, the problem should have been precisely stated, with $1/2$ (or some other number) explicitly specified.